# Two different avatars?

Tags: bug

I've noticed that I seem to have two different avatars.

When I use the chatrooms and visit my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5798798/the-codesee), I see the following **dark blue/purple** avatar:

[image]

[image]

When I look at my questions, or my profile in the navigation bar, I see the following **green** avatar:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Gothdo It hasn't changed.. or not completely.. I have **two different** avatars

Comment: That's still a duplicate. The avatar on your profile looks different because it's bigger.